# Format numbers to strings in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I need to find out how to format numbers as strings. My code is here:

```
return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)+" "+ampm
```

Hours and minutes are integers, and seconds is a float.  the str() function will convert all of these numbers to the tenths (0.1) place.  So instead of my string outputting "5:30:59.07 pm", it would display something like "5.0:30.0:59.1 pm".

Bottom line, what library / function do I need to do this for me?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Starting with Python 3.6, formatting in Python can be done using [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) or *f-strings*:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = 6, 56, 33
f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02} {"pm" if hours > 12 else "am"}'
```

or the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function starting with 2.7:

```
"{:02}:{:02}:{:02} {}".format(hours, minutes, seconds, "pm" if hours > 12 else "am")
```

or the [string formatting `%` operator](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) for even older versions of Python, but see the note in the docs:

```
"%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

And for your specific case of formatting time, there’s [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
import time

t = (0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0, 0, 0)
time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p', t)
```

Answer (score 103):

The OP & accepted answer focus on formatting time, but the OP *question* itself discusses formatting numbers to strings in Python. In many cases, the output requires additional data fields be included along with timestamps, all of which include formatting numbers as strings.

Below are a variety of *non time-based* examples of formatting numbers as strings, and different ways to do so, starting with the existing string format operator (`%`) which has been around for as long as Python has been around (meaning this solution is compatible across Python 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x):

```
>>> "Name: %s, age: %d" % ('John', 35) 
'Name: John, age: 35' 
>>> i = 45 
>>> 'dec: %d/oct: %#o/hex: %#X' % (i, i, i) 
'dec: 45/oct: 055/hex: 0X2D' 
>>> "MM/DD/YY = %02d/%02d/%02d" % (12, 7, 41) 
'MM/DD/YY = 12/07/41' 
>>> 'Total with tax: $%.2f' % (13.00 * 1.0825) 
'Total with tax: $14.07' 
>>> d = {'web': 'user', 'page': 42} 
>>> 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz/%(web)s/%(page)d.html' % d 
'http://xxx.yyy.zzz/user/42.html'
```

Starting in Python 2.6 (meaning it works for 2.x and 3.x), there is an alternative: the `str.format()` method. Here are the equivalent snippets to the above but using `str.format()`:

```
>>> "Name: {0}, age: {1}".format('John', 35) 
'Name: John, age: 35' 
>>> i = 45 
>>> 'dec: {0}/oct: {0:#o}/hex: {0:#X}'.format(i) 
'dec: 45/oct: 0o55/hex: 0X2D' 
>>> "MM/DD/YY = {0:02d}/{1:02d}/{2:02d}".format(12, 7, 41) 
'MM/DD/YY = 12/07/41' 
>>> 'Total with tax: ${0:.2f}'.format(13.00 * 1.0825) 
'Total with tax: $14.07' 
>>> d = {'web': 'user', 'page': 42} 
>>> 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz/{web}/{page}.html'.format(**d) 
'http://xxx.yyy.zzz/user/42.html'
```

Like Python 2.6+, all Python 3 releases (so far) understand how to do both. I shamelessly ripped this stuff straight out of [my hardcore Python intro book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132269937) and the slides for the Intro+Intermediate [Python courses I offer](http://cyberwebconsulting.com) from time-to-time. `:-)`

**Aug 2018 UPDATE**: Of course, now that we have [the f-string feature introduced in 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) (only works in 3.6 and newer), we need the equivalent examples of *that*; yes, another alternative:

```
>>> name, age = 'John', 35
>>> f'Name: {name}, age: {age}'
'Name: John, age: 35'

>>> i = 45
>>> f'dec: {i}/oct: {i:#o}/hex: {i:#X}'
'dec: 45/oct: 0o55/hex: 0X2D'

>>> m, d, y = 12, 7, 41
>>> f"MM/DD/YY = {m:02d}/{d:02d}/{y:02d}"
'MM/DD/YY = 12/07/41'

>>> f'Total with tax: ${13.00 * 1.0825:.2f}'
'Total with tax: $14.07'

>>> d = {'web': 'user', 'page': 42}
>>> f"http://xxx.yyy.zzz/{d['web']}/{d['page']}.html"
'http://xxx.yyy.zzz/user/42.html'
```

Answer (score 12):

### Python 2.6+

It is possible to use the `format()` function, so in your case you can use:

```
return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:.2f} {}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds, ampm)
```

There are multiple ways of using this function, so for further information you can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

### Python 3.6+

f-strings is a new feature that has been added to the language in Python 3.6. This facilitates formatting strings notoriously:

```
return f'{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:.2f} {ampm}'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use C style string formatting:

```
"%d:%d:d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

See here, especially: https://web.archive.org/web/20120415173443/http://diveintopython3.ep.io/strings.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use following to achieve desired functionality

```
"%d:%d:d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the str.format() to make Python recognize any objects to strings.

Answer (score 2):

****I've tried this in Python 3.6.9****

```
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = 9, 33, 35
>>> time = f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02} {"pm" if hours > 12 else "am"}'
>>> print (time)
09:33:35 am
>>> type(time)

<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

*str()* in python on an integer will **not** print any decimal places.

If you have a float that you want to ignore the decimal part, then you can use str(int(floatValue)).

Perhaps the following code will demonstrate:

```
>>> str(5)
'5'
>>> int(8.7)
8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value that includes a decimal, but the decimal value is negligible (ie: 100.0) and try to int that, you will get an error.  It seems silly, but calling float first fixes this.

str(int(float([variable])))