# How to display output as an integer instead of a real number

Tags: python, python-3.x

This isn't my exact code, but I'm basically doing this

```
    EnemyAttack = int(10)
    Move = input("| Cast an attack spell(1) | Cast a defense spell(2) |")
    if Move = ("2"):
       print ("You have casted a defense spell for 2 turns")
       EAN = 2
    if EAN >= 1:
       EnemyAttack = EnemyAttack / 2
       EAN = EAN - 1
    Health = Health - EnemyAttack
```

The code does halve the enemy's attack, however the output is not what i want it to be.

```
print ("You have been damaged for {}".format(EnemyAttack)
```

This displays

```
84.0
```

I want it to output

```
84
```

I have already defined the EnemyAttack as an integer, so I'm confused why it's displayed as a real number. Any solutions? Also if you can, comment using a simple code that I can convert into my situation. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format numbers to strings in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617/format-numbers-to-strings-in-python)

Comment: If it's `EnemyAttack` that it's outputting, then why is it 84 instead of 10 or 5? Are you sure you've transferred your code correctly?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan The 10 was an example, in the real code it was 84, sorry if it caused you any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format it without decimals, rounding it to the nearest whole number:

```
print("You have been damaged for {:.0f}".format(EnemyAttack))
```

`:` is a required separator; everything after it defines formatting instructions for that value. We use the `f` floating point formatter here, and `.0` means *zero digits after the decimal point*. When you do that the decimal point itself is also dropped.

This has the advantage that the number will be rounded *up* as needed:

```
>>> EnemyAttack = 84.0
>>> print("You have been damaged for {:.0f}".format(EnemyAttack))
You have been damaged for 84
>>> EnemyAttack = 84.6
>>> print("You have been damaged for {:.0f}".format(EnemyAttack))
You have been damaged for 85
```

See the [*Formatting Specification Mini-Language* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for the details.

Comment: May i ask what the f is for? The code works perfectly now thanks. But what is the purpose of the f after the 0?

Comment: @MaxyPicky: I linked you to the documentation; everything after the `:` is the formatting specification (everything before is specifying what value to interpolate and format, omitting it uses auto-numbering).

Comment: Quick, and maybe irrelevent, question, but if i place the {.0f} format where a string will take place, will an error occour? e.g.<pre>    word = ("Hello") print ("He said {.0f}.".format(word))    <code>

Comment: @MaxyPicky: yes, because string objects know nothing about the `f` formatting code. `str.format()` delegates formatting to the value itself, so `'Hello'.__format__('.0f')`, which fails.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you cannot define the type of a variabelname.
If you want integer division, you have to use the integer division operator `//`:

```
EnemyAttack = EnemyAttack // 2
```

Comment: +1 This is the root of the problem. My impression is the OP seems to believe that the {} format is not clever enough to recognise and correctly format an integer when it's passed one.