# Beginner python, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a short script to calculate the BMI of three different individuals. I'm still learning stuff so it's nothing fancy. I get all the data I need and can write in most of the stuff. I can't seem to get one thing work though. When trying the below code:

Code:

## BMI Calculator

```
name1 = "X"
height_m1 = 1.7
weight_kg1 = 90

name2 = "Y"
height_m2 = 1.6
weight_kg2 = 100

name3= "Z"
height_m3 = 1.6
weight_kg = 80
```

Above code runs with no errors.

```
def bmi_calc(name, height_m, weight_kg):
    bmi = weight_kg / height_m **2
    print("BMI: ")
    print(bmi)
    if bmi < 25:
        print("Name:", name+".", "BMI:", bmi+".", name, "is not overweight")
    else:
        print("Name:", name+".", "BMI:", bmi+".", name, "is overweight")
```

Above code runs with no errors.

```
results1 = bmi_calc(name1, height_m1, weight_kg1)
results2 = bmi_calc(name2, height_m2, weight_kg2)
results3 = bmi_calc(name3, height_m3, weight_kg3)
```

When I try and plug my 3 variables into the above code, it returns the following error message:

```
BMI:  31.14186851211073
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-c528c04b0723> in <module>()
----> 1 results1 = bmi_calc(name1, height_m1, weight_kg1)
      2 results2 = bmi_calc(name2, height_m2, weight_kg2)
      3 results3 = bmi_calc(name3, height_m3, weight_kg3)

<ipython-input-66-59d41ff4404c> in bmi_calc(name, height_m, weight_kg)
      5         print("Name:", name+".", "BMI:", bmi+".", name, "is not overweight")
      6     else:
----> 7         print("Name:", name+".", "BMI:", bmi+".", name, "is overweight")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

The error seems to be focused on the strings, but I cannot understand why

Comment: Additional tip: If you want 'results', Use 'return' instead of 'print' in your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format numbers to strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617/format-numbers-to-strings-in-python)

Comment: can you explain why the print function does not suffice?

Comment: You can't concatenate a float to a string, you have to convert it to a string too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Name:", name+".", "BMI:", bmi+".", name, "is overweight")
```

In this line, variable `bmi` is a float and `"."` is a string, hence you may not add, convert `bmi` to a string to do that

```
print(... str(bmi)+"." ...)
```

Type conversion will allow two strings to be added.

Comment: Ok, yeah, should have noticed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can write the same thing just converting the float value into a string

```
def bmi_calc(name, height_m, weight_kg):
bmi = weight_kg / height_m **2
print("BMI: ")
print(bmi)
if bmi < 25:
    print("Name:", name + ".", "BMI:", str(bmi) + ".", name, "is not overweight")
else:
    print("Name:", name + ".", "BMI:", str(bmi) + ".", name, "is overweight")
```

Comment: You are welcome, [that's](https://www.tutsmake.com/python-concatenate-string-and-variable-int-float-etc/ ) why your code doesn't work